# How to calculate the total hour worked between two dates?

Tags: java, algorithm, validation, date

I have two dates, hiring 11/19/2013 and endhiring  10/01/2014, both are converted to total hours, without considering the weekends, but they have different years and because of this the output says: the total hours worked was -1200:

```
private int calculateTimeInternship(Vacancy peoplevacancy){
    int hourWorked = 0; 
    Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();  
    Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();    

    date1.setTime(peoplevacancy.getDthiring());  
    date2.setTime(peoplevacancy.getDtendhiring());  

    int initiation = date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);  
    int end = date2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);  

    int amountDay = (initiation - end) + 1;  

    for (; initiation <= end; inicio++){  
        if (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1   || date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 7)  
        amountDay--;  

        date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
    }

    hourWorked = amountDay * 4 //4 hour per day;
    return hourWorked ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) can help you, but I'm never able to use it because of its license.

If like me, Joda is not appropriate for you, you can solve this problem as follows:

```
initialize endDate object
initialize startDate object
initialize weeksBetween as 
    milliseconds between end&start/milliseconds per day, divided by seven (integer floor). 
    //may need to normalize dates and set them to be both midnight or noon or some common time
initialize daysBetween = weeksBetween*5 // in any continuous 7 days, 5 are weekdays.
initialize curDay=startDate + weeksBetween*7 days

while(curDay is not endDate)
   add a day to curDay
   if(curDay is not weekend)
      daysBetween++
output daysBetween* 4
```

You can get the milliseconds between them by converting the calendars to [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (Calendar has such a method to do this)

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```
private int calculateTimeInternship(Vacancy vacancy) {
    return 4 * ((int)(vacancy.getDtendhiring().getTime() / 86400000L - vacancy.getDthiring().getTime() / 86400000L) + 1);  
}
```

By dividing by `86400000` *first*, then subtracting, it doesn't matter what time of day each date have.

FYI `86400000` is the number of milliseconds in a day.

Comment: Ignoring weekends is what makes it complicated. And I wouldn't put that 1/4 factor in the calculation.

Comment: @John the 1/4 is what completes the calculation - the number of hours worked per day is 4, so my math is correct isn't it? And I took "without considering weekends" to mean that weekends are treated as normal working days.

Comment: What I mean is straight division on the millisecond per day. Keep the 4*outside for clarity and maybe write the 86400000L as 86400_000L (I find it makes it clearer that it is milliseconds per day & the 000 is a visible sign there isn't a 0 missing). It is still correct and all, but it is easier to make a mistake when having a long string of 0's and doing the mathematical operations yourself. The other issue is that it isn't 4*number of days, it is 4*number of weekdays I believe.

Comment: @john you are spot on about the "4 outside". My previous code was brittle regarding the time of day of each date. Now it can be any time and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You are already looping through every day of the internship, so why not simply count workdays?

```
int amountDay = 0;
while (date1.compareTo(date2) <= 0) {
    if (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 1
    &&  date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 7)  
        amountDay++;  
    date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
}
```

By the way, your original code has a subtle "off by one" bug. The subtraction for the total amountDays *excludes* the end day, but the loop *includes* the end day when deducting weekends.