# Java - Calculate Number of Weeks Between 2 Dates

Tags: java, date

Is it possible to determine the number of weeks between 2 dates in Java/JSP? For example if date one is 2013-10-29 and date two is 2013-11-12, I would like the number of weeks to be output.

Could somebody pleas help? :-)

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963147/get-the-number-of-weeks-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1):

[Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) can help you, but I'm never able to use it because of its license.

If like me, Joda is not appropriate for you, you can solve this problem as follows:

```
initialize endDate object
initialize startDate object
initialize weeksBetween as 
    milliseconds between end&start/milliseconds per day, divided by seven (integer floor, ceiling or round this). 
    //may need to normalize dates and set them to be both midnight or noon or some common time
output weeksBetween
```

You can get the milliseconds between them by converting the calendars to [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (Calendar has such a method to do this).

I lifted this from: [How to calculate the total hour worked between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872023/how-to-calculate-the-total-hour-worked-between-two-dates/19872082#19872082)

Comment: So many buggy answers for this. But this was the best one that solved it for me. Just be sure to convert both from and to dates to the same weekday

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html#weeksBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) library :

Object **Weeks**, method **[weeksBetween](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html#weeksBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29)** :

Comment: I'm trying that, I am using joda-time-2.3.jar located in the WEB-INF\lib folder but despite using import org.joda.time.* I am getting the error Weeks cannot be resolved using the code:

String dFrom = ps.utils.gv(request, "dFrom");
String dTo = ps.utils.gv(request, "dTo");
int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(dFrom, dTo).getWeeks();